# Chaining scopes and accessing other objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I have to models, `Library` and `Book`.

```
class Library
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  has_many :books

  scope :first_scope, -> do
    logger.debug Book.all.entries
    where(name: "Foo")
  end

  scope :second_scope, -> do
    logger.debug Book.all.entries
    where(name: "Bar")
  end
end

class Book
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, type: String
  belongs_to :library
end
```

Now if I chain the scopes like this `Library.first_scope.second_scope`, the debug for the first one returns the list of existing books, which is what I would expect, but the second one returns me the list of existing libraries, as if I did `logger.debug Library.all.entries`.

Why is that? Why can I access the `Book` collection in the first scope, but not in the second one? And how could I access the `Book` collection in the second scope?

Comment: Are you positive about the debug being from the same statements? Perhaps you could test with `logger.debug "xxx #{your_code} xxx"`?

Comment: I already surrounded them just to make sure but yes it is from these two debugs. I tried with `byebug` to access `Book.all.entries` in `second_scope` too, same results.

Comment: Does it have the same effect if you change the order of scopes? `Library.second_scope.first_scope`

Comment: Well same effect in the sense that a list of `Book` is returned in `second_scope` and a list of `Library` in `first_scope`. So the log depends on the order of the scopes.

Comment: Have to say @evuez, it's a strange one! I would try to ensure that `Book.table_name` is returning the intended value in the second scope, using a Byebug session.

Comment: @Humza There's no `.table_name` with Mongoid, but I tried a `Book.create` just to make sure it called the `Book` model, and it does. It seems to only mess things up when reading from the database...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Moped, which seems to work fine... No idea why though.

```
scope :second_scope, -> do
  logger.debug Book.collection.find.first  # Returns a Book, yay!
  where(name: "Bar")
end
```